# Numpy efficient way to get adiacent indices or values in matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Say you have a matrix A with strings in it.

```
[["a", "A", ""],
 ["A", "a", ""],
 ["a", "", ""]]
```

The objective is to find all the "squares" where there are orthogonal adjacent upper case letters and no orthogonal adjacent lower case letters.
The result should be like this:

```
[[True, False, True],
 [False, True, False],
 [True, False, False]]
```

Now, what I have done until now was to create a dictionary adjSquares that links the cartesian indices of each square with the cartesian indices of the adiacent squares.

Every time I have to make the check described above I do the following:

```
np.reshape([any(isupper(A[i,j] for (i,j) in adjSquares[(row,col)])) and not any(islower(A[i,j] for (i,j) in adjSquares[(row,col)])) for row in range(3) for col in range(3)], (3,3))
```

Is there a way to get the same result using vectorized operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one based on [`2D convolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) + `masking` -

```
def getmask_based_on_lettercases(a):
    # Generate "star" kernel wtih zero at center as the kernel
    kernel = np.zeros((3,3),dtype=int)
    kernel[:,1] = kernel[1] = 1
    kernel[1,1] = 0

    # Not empty cells mask
    nE = a!=''

    # Mask of at least one uppercase string neighborhood
    U = (np.char.upper(a)==a) & nE
    upper_and_not_empty = convolve2d(U,kernel,'same')>0

    # Mask of at least one lowercase string neighborhood
    L = (np.char.lower(a)==a) & nE
    lower_and_not_empty = convolve2d(L,kernel,'same')>0

    # Let's fulfil "no orthogonal adjacent lower case letters" case
    return upper_and_not_empty & ~lower_and_not_empty
```

Sample runs -

```
In [352]: a
Out[352]: 
array([['a', 'A', ''],
       ['A', 'a', ''],
       ['a', '', '']], dtype='<U1')

In [353]: getmask_based_on_lettercases(a)
Out[353]: 
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False]])
```

Now, let's test out - `no orthogonal adjacent lower case letters` case, as mentioned in the question by setting `a[2,1]` as a lowercase one -

```
In [354]: a[2,1] = 'a'

In [355]: a
Out[355]: 
array([['a', 'A', ''],
       ['A', 'a', ''],
       ['a', 'a', '']], dtype='<U1')

In [356]: getmask_based_on_lettercases(a)
Out[356]: 
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could is that you make another array, which is lowercase of original data:

```
dd = np.array([["a","A",""],["A","a",""],["","",""]])
dnew = np.char.lower(dd);
```

And you check, whether new data equals old data:

```
dd == dnew
```

Neverthess, it does not work with the empty characters, but at least the solution is vectorized.